# CTRL+C w/ Spring Boot & Gradle Kills Gradle Daemon

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I use the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to start a Tomcat server & my app. I start the Tomcat server via `gradle bootRun`. I've also enabled the Gradle daemon, in hopes to make Gradle builds go faster.

However, enabling the daemon is for naught. Every time I stop the server via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, then start the server again with `gradle bootRun`, I encounter the message:

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> not only stops the Tomcat server under the covers of Spring Boot, but also kills the Gradle daemon. Which defeats the purpose of Gradle's daemon mode.

Is there a better way I should be stopping the server, hopefully via command line interface in the same terminal for which I started tomcat with `gradle bootRun`, that keeps the Gradle daemon alive?

Answer (score 5):

This is still an issue in Gradle 4. My best compromise/solution (building off charlie_pl's answer):

1. Press `ctrl+z` to send the running process to the background.
2. Kill the process like: `kill $(ps aux | grep "MyApp" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')`
3. Restart: `./gradlew run ...`

Comment: Where `"MyApp"` is probably `"tomcat"`, and step #3 should probably just be running `fg` to resume the Gradle process -- or better yet, append that to the end of step #2 as `&& fg`.

Comment: Well, in my case I was using Dropwizard, so not `tomcat`, but sure. Also there is no process to bring back with `fg`; we've killed it in step 2. The only reason I'm sending the process to the background is so I don't have to go to a new terminal to kill the process.

Comment: My comment was specifically regarding the use of *Spring Boot* and *tomcat* with Gradle (as described by the OP).  If you're not using Spring Boot, it could be a different story, but my intuition is that if you aren't going to run `fg`, you might as well just `Ctrl-C`.  By the way, when you run `fg`, it allows Spring/Gradle to do some cleanup before returning the command-prompt.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the Spring Boot plugin, so presumably there is no 'bootStop' command (as there is in the Jetty plugin). Also, after an extensive search, I don't think there is a command-line option for the desired result.

One option, though admittedly a kludge, is to use the Tooling API. (Full code example [is here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_Tooling_API).)

The idea is to start the long-running task in a Groovy script. On command, the script will stop the task and call `gradle tasks` to tickle the daemon.

From the GitHub code linked above, a long-running task could be:

```
task runService() << {
    ant.delete(file: "runService.log")
    def count = 0
    while(true) {
        new File("runService.log").withWriterAppend {
            it.writeLine("[runService] count: ${count}")
        }
        println "sleeping ...."
        try { Thread.sleep(5 * 1000) } catch (Exception ex) {}
        count++
    }
}
```

The idea behind the Groovy script is to start the task in a background thread, and then send a cancel token upon receipt of the command.

For clarity, I'll illustrate two sections. The first section is the background thread:

```
class BuildRunner implements Runnable {
    def connector
    def tokenSource
    def taskName

    BuildRunner(connector, tokenSource, taskName) {
        this.connector = connector
        this.tokenSource = tokenSource
        this.taskName = taskName
    }

    public void run() {
        def connection = connector.connect()        
        try {            
            def build = connection.newBuild()
            build.withCancellationToken(tokenSource.token())
            build.setStandardOutput(System.out)
            build.setStandardError(System.err)
            build.forTasks(taskName)
            build.run()
            println "${taskName} is finishing ..."
        } catch(BuildCancelledException bcex) {
            println "received cancel signal"
            println "tickling daemon ..."
            tickleDaemon(connector)
            println "Done."
            System.exit(0)
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            println "caught exception : " + ex
        } finally {            
          connection.close()        
        }        
    }

    def tickleDaemon = { connector ->
        final String TASKS = "tasks"
        def connection = connector.connect()        
        def build = connection.newBuild()
        build.forTasks(TASKS)
        build.run()
    }
}
```

and the other section is the main console:

```
// main -----------

// edit as appropriate
final String TASK_NAME = "runService"
final String GRADLE_INSTALL_DIR = "/Users/measter/tools/gradle-2.14.1"
final String PROJECT_DIR = "../service"

def connector = GradleConnector.newConnector()
connector.useInstallation(new File(GRADLE_INSTALL_DIR))
connector.forProjectDirectory(new File(PROJECT_DIR))

def tokenSource = connector.newCancellationTokenSource()

println "starting ${TASK_NAME}"
def buildRunner = new BuildRunner(connector, tokenSource, TASK_NAME)
new Thread(buildRunner).start()

def console = new Scanner(System.in)
println "Enter a command (S: stop task, Q: quit): "

while (console.hasNextLine()) {
    def lineTokenizer = new Scanner(console.nextLine())
    String token = lineTokenizer.next()
    if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
        tokenSource.cancel()
    } else if (token.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
        println "Done."
        System.exit(0)
    }
}
```

This code can easily be customized to execute other tasks, to restart a task etc. It hints at a glorified wrapper around personal command-line usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explain from the core dev for why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will kills the daemon.

> It's always been this way "by design", but we want to move away from it so the daemon isn't killed so often. I think there are cases where we don't propagate the ctrl+c, but that's by luck.
>
> If you look at what we're doing for continuous mode in 2.5, we're adding ctrl+d to exit the Gradle process without killing the daemon. We have a similar problem as bootRun with our Play application support (playRun), which uses the same mechanism (ctrl+d). I think we'll eventually do something like this generically, but we need to provide an alternative way for existing build scripts to read stdin before we capture input all of the time.

— [Sterling Greene](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/ctrl-c-during-running-build-also-kills-daemon/10158/2) (Gradle Core Dev)

Answer (score 2):

`bootRun` is a convenience feature of [`spring-boot-gradle-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications).  It lets you perform two steps in one command, and it has the *very minor* benefit of not generating a `.jar` file in the process.  It also has the potentially *major* benefit...

> If devtools has been added to your project it will automatically
>   monitor your application for changes.

If you aren't utilizing the live update features of `bootRun`, **you can solve this problem by performing the build/run sequence as two commands**, as described at ["Running your application"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-as-a-packaged-application).  Because the second command does not involve Gradle, you can now `Ctrl-C` the server without the disadvantage of leaving Gradle in a `CANCELED` state.

Here is an example of applying such an approach:

```
gradle build && java -jar build/libs/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

---

On the other hand, if you *are* using [devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), you may not need to frequently restart the server manually -- just rebuild and the server will restart itself (for Groovy you only need to update the source file).

> Applications that use spring-boot-devtools will automatically restart whenever files on the classpath change.

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

...And if you're using an IDE (e.g. 'vscode'), it may automatically compile your java files, so just saving a java file can initiate a server restart, indirectly.  Then **Java becomes just as seamless as Groovy in this regard**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may have been resolved in 3.1 https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes#more-resilient-daemon

Comment: The correct link now is https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/release-notes.html#more-resilient-daemon

Comment: @StephenFriedrich You can try simply killing the app process, this should preserve the daemon, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I started dropwizard application, and killing a daemon considerabely increased time to restart the application.

**Easy Solution:**
In the end I've simply searched for dropwizard process, and killed it in commandline (simple kill & ps aux & grep combination). This closes the app and fails the build, but preserves the daemon.