# Neither Spring Boot Actuator + Hal-Browser nor DevTools working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, browser, spring-boot-actuator, hal

**Updated**: Attached `pom.xml` and `application.property` and some more error / warning msgs.

Hi I am very new to Spring Boot and just taking some classes on Udemy for it.

While following through a class, I create a starter project via spring.io and added actuator and Hal browser dependencies including Dev tools.

Just ran my app and tried to go to `localhost:8080/application` & `/browser` as well but I get 404.

What am I doing wrong?

I wrote a simple bean which returns a hard coded value and then print that, I changed the value to test Dev tools and it didn’t restart the resource , I had to kill and restart the app to reflect the new changes ..

How can I check what the issue ?

I can provide console grab if needed.

Please help.

**Update**: I don't know the significance of the following so putting it in here.

in the XML editor hal is red underlined with the following msg on hover:

> The managed version is 3.0.5.RELEASE The artifact is managed in org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Kay-SR5

in the XML editor devtools is red underlined with the following msg on hover:

> The managed version is 2.0.0.RELEASE The artifact is managed in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myoxigen.training.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>library</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`application.properties` file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework = DEBUG
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: Please provide pom.xml and application.properties,it will help us to know your config and context.

Comment: hope now the information will be more useful, i have added both

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503571/spring-boot-2-actuator-metrics-endpoint-not-working

Answer (score 6):

*Note: This answer is based on Spring Boot 2 (paths and properties have changed from version 1).*

Your `pom.xml` looks fine to me.  To get the "HAL Browser" to work with actuator you should have starters: `web`, `actuator`, and `Rest Repositories HAL Browser`.  I recommend [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) as a nice way to construct an initial valid project structure.

The default path for the actuator is `/actuator`.  Health, for example, is at `/actuator/health`.

To view the actuator endpoints in the HAL Browser, go to `/browser/index.html#/actuator`.

You can change the actuator path in `application.properties` by setting the following.

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
```

To run your server, use the following console command:

```
./mvnw clean spring-boot:run
```

If you have `DevTools` in your project, then changes to files in your classpath will restart the server.  See my further comments on how to take advantage of DevTools [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46506588).

---

Here's the relevant documentation on a single page for easy searching:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle

Comment: I just saw somewhere that `/actuator` was briefly changed to `/application` for Spring Boot 2.0 -- but as of the `2.0.0-RELEASE`, it's back to `/actuator`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Add this Dependency:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>`enter code here`

And then go to link:
http://localhost:8080/browser/index.html#
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 2.2 apps should use **spring-data-rest-hal-explorer** rather than **spring-data-rest-hal-browser**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For enabling actuator, add this into the property file (application.properties)

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Restart the Spring boot application and access the actuator endpoints using:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/
```

the health of the application can also be monitored using:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

dependency required:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ain't you were studying a course by "in28minutes"? =) Anyway when I studied on a [Spring Boot for Beginners in 10 Steps](https://in28minutes1.teachable.com/p/spring-boot-for-beginners-in-10-steps) course, I faced the same issue with accessing `http://localhost:8080/application`.

For `http://localhost:8080/browser` I got a plain `json`:

```
{"cause":null,"message":"Fragment must not be empty"}
```

In `pom.xml` I had the same dependencies as you outlined in question.

Some googling brought me to [this](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-data/use-hal-browser-spring-data-rest-springboot-mysql) article. In section named "II. Hal Browser" you can see a screenshot, where in browser a link is `http://localhost:8080/browser/index.html#`. If use this link, then Hal Browser should magically appear.

So `/index.html#` was the only puzzle piece you missed.

Note: above approach worked with Spring Boot version 2.1.7

**EDIT**: despite the fact that Hal Browser itself works with above approach, it still doesn't show actuator endpoints. And DevTools also ain't working for me.